# Wakanda Server solution.quitServer() sequence of operations

Tags: server, exit, wakanda

I have already read the thread:
[Wakanda Server scripted clean shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671411/wakanda-server-scripted-clean-shutdown)

This does not address my question.

We are running Wakanda Server 11.197492.

We want an automated, orderly, ensured shut-down of Wakanda Server - no matter which version we are running.

Before we give the "shutdown" command, we will stop inbound traffic for 1 to 2 minutes, to ensure that no httpHandlers are running when we shut-down.

We have scripted a single SharedWorker process to look for the "shutdown" command, and execute solution.quitServer().

At this time no other ShareWorker processes are running, and no active threads should be executing. This will likely not always be the case.

When this is executed, is a "solution quit" guaranteed?
Is solution.quitServer() the best way to initiate an automated solution shutdown?
Will there be a better way?
Is there a way to know of any of the Solution's Projects are currently executing threads prior to shutting down?
If more than 1 Project issues a solution.quitServer() method, within a few seconds of eachother, will that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

`solution.quitServer()` is probably not the best way to shutdown your server as it will be deprecated in the next major release.

I would recommend to send a sigkill as you point out in your question.
[Wakanda Server scripted clean shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671411/wakanda-server-scripted-clean-shutdown)

Some fix have been done on v1.1.0 to safely close wakanda server after a `kill`.