# server stop systematically when I upload my model

Tags: wakanda

### Could somebody help me !

I see no particular place in all the documentation for that.
When I upload my model....**my server disconnect systematically**.

1. My WebPage shows in the console : an error 504
   *zone.js:2744 GET http://localhost:4201/rest/$catalog/$all 504 (Gateway Timeout)*
   [image]
2. I try to kill the process with : sh killWakanda.sh Wakanda Server in
   the terminal....this was the answer from Xiang in the "stackoverflow question :
   [Wakanda Server scripted clean shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671411/wakanda-server-scripted-clean-shutdown/35697989#35697989)

   3. when restarting wakanda , i receive sometimes this screen
      [image]
   4. I don't see any documentation to administrate the localhost server and data in one project with wakanda...and angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Address already in use" indicates your Angular project (web) is still running after you killed Wakanda process.

My answer from last year showed how to shut down Wakanda Server, which listens to port 8080 and 8081, etc. 
In Angular projects, the studio also uses webpack dev server for development. It listens to port 4200, 4201, etc. 
In versions after 2.0.0, Wakanda Task manager allows you to stop/start Wakanda server and Angular server in studio represented by 'backend' and 'web' project.

To shut down webpack dev servers Manually. You could run this in terminal:

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:4201 | xargs kill -9
```

Note the port number (4201) might change if you run Angular server multiple times.